# Change dependent gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, soap4r

I need switching gem on which other gem relies. So in particular:

i have adwords4r gem which relies to old soap4r(which has issues on 1.9.2). I want to change gem on which adwords4r relies to other one(that almost similar but has some tweaks on new ruby versions). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adwords4r gem's [Readme](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-ruby/wiki/Readme) says that the gem has been deprecated in favor of the `google-adwords-api` gem (which relies on `savon` instead of `soap4r`). You should consider using that instead (and the `google-adwords-api` gem is very active -- their most recent release was 5 days ago).

While you could probably patch the existing `adwords4r` gem to work with a newer version of `soap4r`, it probably will not be as easy as specifying a newer version (i.e. I'm sure there's a reason the developers locked it to that specific version).

Comment: Thanks, didn't noticed deprecation. I'm not sure i can switch to non-deprecated gem(big chunks of code written for old one), will try however. I've found forks of soap4r that working with 1.9, i don't think there will be issues, so question remains: How do i change gem dependency?